# Get text inside quotes " " and sentence before than in R regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataset like this:

```
Topic     Content
Happy     Jane said. "I am a happy girl!" She walked away.Running towards May."Hi, she said... I am bored. 2.8% BORED." haha
Sad       Today is gloomy. "She added," said Saddy.
```

I would like extract the text inside the quotations, and 1 sentence before the quotation sentence.

After which, I would like to put each quotation and sentence before in a row.

Below is the output I would like to achieve:

```
Topic     Content
Happy     Jane said. "I am a happy girl!" 
Happy     Running towards May."Hi, she said...I am bored. 2.8% BORED"
Sad       Today is gloomy. "She added," said Saddy.
```

Below is my data:

```
structure(list(Topic = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Happy", "Sad"), 
class = "factor"), Content = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Jane said. \"I am a happy girl!\" She walked away.Running towards May.\"Hi, she said... I am bored. 2.8%   BORED.\" haha", "Today is gloomy. \"She added,\" said Saddy."), class =  "factor")), .Names = c("Topic", "Content"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I have tried but it cannot work. I cannot even do extracting:

```
df <-  stack(setNames(lapply(gsub('[^"]+\\"([^)]+)\\".*', '\\1', x$Content, perl=TRUE), grep, pattern='\\"', value=TRUE), x$Topic))[2:1]
colnames(df) <- colnames(x)[c(1,2)]
res <- merge(x[1:1], df)
```

Currently this is my output:

```
[1] "Jane said. \"I am a happy girl!\".Running towards May.\"Hi, she said... I am bored. 2.8% BORED.\""
[2] "Today is gloomy. \"She added,\"."
```

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match the description you've given so it's unclear what criteria you want to split the strings on.

Comment: what does "1 sentence before the quotation sentence" means?

Comment: It means: I am pretty. Jo said he is smart. "Intelligent too.. I guess?" Haha. Hence, I would like to get: Jo said he is smart. "Intelligent too.. I guess?" Remove the "I am pretty." and "Haha" @ColonelBeauvel

Comment: I do not know how to do it. Updated, sorry about that @Jay

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? Regex Sample: https://regex101.com/r/xE2wQ2/1

Comment: I posted this as an answer since I also included an example to what he is probably trying to do.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Hi, thanks, this is what I want to achieve. But can't work

Comment: what do you mean can't work? maybe there is something wrong with your implementation.

Comment: And I'm sorry, coz I'm not familiar with the programming language you are using. What programming language are you using?

Comment: And by the way, please make sure to escape again the quotation mark in my regex.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag I am using R programming language

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag What do you mean by escape again with the quotation mark?

Comment: first, can you change your strings? into double quotation instead of single quotation?

Comment: `df <-  stack(setNames(lapply(gsub("[^\"]+\"([^)]+)\".*", "\\1", ...........`

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag If i use double quote, then I will have error.

Comment: `df <- stack(setNames(lapply(gsub("([^\\.]+\\.\\s*\"[^\"]+\")",`

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Error: unexpected ']' in "gsub("[^"]"

Comment: try the one I just commented.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Okay, now it does not have error message, but still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: try replacning `'\\1'` with `"\\1"`

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Tried, still doesn't work

Comment: Maybe there is something with your code.  Sorry I can't interpet your code, since I have no idea of R language. Try asking another question why your code doesn't work, I guess the problem is not with the regex pattern. Don't forget to mark this as an answer if it answered your regex problem.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Thanks for your help. Could you also help in the pattern. Because I do not know how to do as well. Sorry. Is like for each sentence and the quote, it is one row, then another 1 sentence and 1 quote will another row. Then I do not know what pattern to use. Thanks

Comment: can you describe with an example?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag And this is the code that I want to extract but cannot capture the text I want:  gsub("([^\\.]+\\.\\s*\"[^\"]+\")", "\\1", x)

Comment: @akrun Could you help me in this? Thanks

Comment: @stribizhev Could you help me in this? Thanks